# how to include jquery plugins in an ASP.NET project

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to include this jquery plugin in my asp.net project: http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#

However I always get an Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error.  I want this plugin to be on every page so I thought I need to include it in my _Layout file.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

So I have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script src="~/Scripts/sidr-package-1.2.1/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/sidr-package-1.2.1/stylesheets/jquery.sidr.dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#simple-menu').sidr();
    });
</script>
```

```
@*From their sample *@
<a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">Toggle menu</a>

<div id="sidr">
    <!-- Your content -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">

    @RenderBody()

</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: It relies on jQuery, so the script reference needs to be after jQuery on the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation shows that the Sidr plugin needs to be loaded after jQuery like so:

```
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include the Sidr JS -->
<script src="javascripts/sidr/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
```

You are rendering the jQuery bundle at the bottom of the page whilst referencing the jQuery.sidr.js plugin in the `<head>` of the page. Move the `<script src="~/Scripts/sidr-package-1.2.1/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>` after the rendering of the bundle at the bottom of the `<body>`

Comment: OHHHHH.  Damn that makes sense.  I never thought about the order of loading scripts.  DOH!  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I used this by two methods. First is removing @Scripts.Render bundles and adding my own scripts like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>
```

And if you want to use Like @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
See in the App_Start> Bundle config that jquery is present or not..